# Does it make sense to use a timestamp before saving or when saving to database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Question is pretty forward and it is bothering me for quite some time now. Perhaps any of you has an interesting view on this matter.

When creating an object lets say a memo. 
This memo has a string (for the text obviously)
And a user id who has edited said text.

And this memo object is going to be saved to the database.

Is it common to add the current time to the object (eg. add a DateTime field / property) and save that object to db?

Or use the the current time of the database eg. when the row is inserted DateTime.Now in DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your application may run on multiple machines and users which may have different time zones or wrong time on their devices, the first option you proposed could affect data's integrity and you will end up with an unsuncronised database.

Comment: That could be true, but if one it was interested in the time when the post was created (locally) then using the database time might not work in such a way.

Comment: That depends on application context. On this case I think would be better to add a second datetime column on database to fill our needs. We may want to save the moment when the user started to create a new record, but also the moment which he decide to press the save button, but the real data which tell us the moment when we "officially" have a new record on database, it's to get it on insert.

Comment: Good point. Marked as answer (although I am curious on possible other ideas)

Answer (score 2):

I feel it would not make much difference though it really depends on your requirement and project architecture. If you are interested in showing the time to user and you use some queue or background worker to insert row to DB (that is there could be some difference in time between creation of object and insertion into SQL), then it perhaps make sense to get the time at the time of creation of object. Else, if it only for record keeping then DB timestamp should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Although your example is simple one it may represent typical scenario in enterprise environment. So, instead of one user and memo there may be lots of users, lots of tasks to be executed by those users and there are supervisors who are monitoring how users are performing. With that in mind you should try to log everything that you can since supervisors will ask for different productivity reports. And basic elements of such reports are "Start time" and "End time" of activity.

That said, it is of lesser importance which time you are using as long as activities of all users may be compared. Do have in mind that some activities may be executed in different time zones. This leads us to the fact that time used for events (such as start time and end time) should come from common source. Either some middle layer or database.

Implicitly, you need to log user activities. So you will have a method that will have several parameters that are sufficient for capturing user activities. Execution of such method should be on middle or database layer and therefore time registered should be consistent and comparable.

With this approach you have possibility to extend your definition of captured events (not only start and end time but also some other relevant moments).